# windows transfer file via seriabl port cmd

Tags: cmd, serial-port

I was trying to figure out sending file via serial port on windows, as the below picture[image]

I know on linux we could do

```
cat [file] > /dev/ttyS0
```

or vice verse

```
cat [file] < /dev/ttyS0
```

I also know on windows type operates samely as cat, so combined together, I modified baud rate and hope get the file transfered ...

```
type [file] > comport:
```

but as shown in picture, I was stuck in waiting forever, any idea to checkout if the file started transfering (like some verbose printout)?

---

after long wait ...

like one hour and a half, I got the process done (prompted with E:\scp in this case), but I did not find where the file locates in my com3 device, still need some help ...

Comment: What kind of device is attached to your COM3: port?

Comment: A mips based busybox device, is this clear? Any more information needed?

Comment: Is your remaining question about where the file is located inside the mips based busybox device? If so, that probably depends on the specific device.

Comment: since I could not find it, so I was thinking the transfer was not successful, but how do I make sure it failed, or how do I get its progress?